# Printing and concatenation with Parse::RecDescent

Tags: perl, parsing, grammar, parse-recdescent

I am testing the grammar from [P::RD tutorial](http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/06/13/recdecent.html) in order to develop my own grammar.
I haven't figured out how to print a string declaration and append '$' to the front of it.
For example "STRING sDir" should print out "$sDir". It is simple enough to just do a $string =~ s/STRING /\$/, but what about the case where there is assignment? eg. "STRING sDir = aNewDir".

Here is the grammar

```
OP       : m([-+*/%])      # Mathematical operators
INTEGER  : /[-+]?\d+/      # Signed integers
VARIABLE : /\w[a-z0-9_]*/i # Variable
STRING   : /STRING/i       # String declaration

expression : INTEGER OP expression
          { return main::expression(@item) }
          | VARIABLE OP expression
          { return main::expression(@item) }
          | INTEGER
          | VARIABLE
          { return $main::VARIABLE{$item{VARIABLE}} }
```

I am starting to think that regex will suffice, but want to know how to create a complex one for comma separated declarations such as "STRING, foo, bar" -> $foo; $bar;

Answer (score 2):

I'm not *completely* following your question. You've only defined `STRING` as a token, you haven't given it any semantic actions. It's the rules below--which appear in the tutorial--which tell us what to do with the tokens.

```
print_instruction : /print/i expression
                  { print $item{expression}."\n" }
assign_instruction : VARIABLE "=" expression
                   { $main::VARIABLE{$item{VARIABLE}} = $item{expression} }

instruction : print_instruction
            | assign_instruction

startrule: instruction(s /;/)
```

- The bottom rule says that we're looking for one or more instructions, separated by a semi-colon.
- The `instruction` rule says an instruction is either a assignment or a print instruction.
- The print instruction takes the word `print` and an `expression` and prints the result of the expression.
- The assignment instruction takes a variable, literal `'='`, and an expression and assigns the result of the expression to the name in the `%main::VARIABLE` hash.
- `expression` has two actions, one for a compound expression which calls `&main::expression` and one for variables which retrieves the named value from the `%main::VARIABLE` hash.

You have just created a token type, but no rule depends on that token. Further more, I get a gist of what you want to do, but not enough that I can give guidance on creating semantic actions for what you want to do.

Not knowing where exactly you wanted to put the instruction, I just added the following case to `expression`:

```
         | 'STRING' /[\p{Alpha}_]\w*/
         { return '$' . $item[2] }
```

It means it looks for the exact string `'STRING'` followed by an identifier sequence. So you can use it like so:

```
print STRING vvv
```

And get `$vvv`.

---

***EDIT***:

If I understand your comment correctly, I added a `string_instruction` rule to `instruction` and defined it as:

```
string_instruction : 'STRING' /[\p{Alpha}_]\w*/
                   { print "\$$item[2]"; }
```

And I added to the examples:

```
print "STRING v\n";  $parser->startrule( "STRING v" );
```

which prints `$v`.

Comment: I understand how the engine works already. My question is: Just like a print_instruction prints an expression using the print command in the action, how can I print a STRING expression with a '$' in front?

Comment: Well it works. I actually tried something similar awhile ago, but maybe I wasn't calling the subrule in a rule. Thanks